# Erro de NullPointer Exception ao trazer dados Fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou com um erro de NullPointerException ao tentar retornar os dados de um Fragment. O erro de NPE é bem nesta linha:

```
String comentarioFoto = fragment_obj.campoComentarioFoto.getText().toString();
```

Vejam o meu código da activity:

```
public class LayoutActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

     Fragment1 fragment_obj;

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private WrapData wd;
    private String answer;

    File caminhoFoto;
    File caminhoVideo;
    VideoView videoview;
    Spinner campoDepartamento;

    Button btnenviaVideo;
    Button btnenviaFoto;

    private String[] departamentoNome = new String[]{"Assistência Social", "Administração", "Agricultura", "Educação", "Finanças", 
            "Indústria Comércio e Turismo", "Planejamento e Urbanismo", "Transportes", "Obras e Serviços Públicos e Urbanos"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /* Variáveis dos botões do campo foto e Video */

        btnenviaFoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvarFoto);
        btnenviaVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvarVideo);

        /* Recupera os dados do Fragment */

        Fragment1 fragment_obj = (Fragment1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerFragment);
        String comentarioFoto = fragment_obj.campoComentarioFoto.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(comentarioFoto);


    }
}
```

Código do Fragment:

```
package br.com.example.souprogresso;

// FRAGMENTO RESPONSAVEL PELO LAYOUT DE FOTO

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    EditText campoComentarioFoto;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_1, container, false);

        campoComentarioFoto = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_comentarioFoto);
        //String comentarioFoto = campoComentarioFoto.getText().toString();

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

XML do fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/containerFragment"
     >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_tirarFoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:onClick="tirarFoto"
                android:text="Tirar Foto" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_capturaFoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:onClick="selecionarFoto"
                android:text="Capturar Foto do Celular" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_abrirMapa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="Buscar Localização" />


            <TextView
                android:text="Digite um Comentário"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_comentarioFoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:hint="Digite um comentário"
                 />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_salvarFoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:onClick="salvarBDFoto"
                android:text="Enviar Foto"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: cara tá muito estranho esse erro. Não consigo resolver. Ele simplesmente não pega os valores que tento passar

Answer (score 1):

Estamos assumindo que você declarou o fragment no xml da Activity , ok? Porque se não tiver feito isso, o fragment ainda não está adicionado na activity.

O segundo ponto é que o fragment pode não estar adicionado a Activity no local onde você está tentando obter o valor do campo.

Então, você pode sobrescrever esse método para saber a hora certa de fazer essa operação:

```
 @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

        if(fragment instanceof Fragment1){
            ((Fragment1)fragment).campoComentarioFoto.getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

Esse código não faz muito sentido para mim, mas apenas para você entender o que possa estar acontecendo no seu caso.